# How to prevent clang from turning "#warning ..." statement into error when -Werror is used?

Tags: gcc, clang, warnings

Gcc has a compiler option `-Wno-error=cpp` which prevents compiler from turning "#warning ..." into error. However, clang doesn't support this option. Does clang have similar option?

Answer (score 1):

Clang option `-Wno-error=\#warnings` is equivalent of gcc's `-Wno-error=cpp`. Escape `\` is needed in Linux. Verified with clang-3.8 in Linux.